# $lightning.createcomponent callback function return before component setCallback

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-out

Lightning App: NewOppLEXApp

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:OpportunityLEX" />
</aura:application>
```

Lighting Component: OpportunityLEX

```
<aura:component controller="abc" implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<aura:attribute name="newRec" type="controller"/>
<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib" /></aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
    init : function(component, event, helper) {
        var objId = component.get("v.recordId");
        console.log(objId);
        
        var action = component.get("c.method");
        console.log(action);
        action.setParams({
            "recId" : objId
        });
        
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            console.log('Setcallback');
            var state = response.getState();
            if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set("v.newRec", response.getReturnValue());
                    var recordTypeId = component.get("v.newRec.recordType");
                    var returnURL = component.get("v.newRec.returnURL");
                    var entity = component.get("v.newRec.entity");                    
                    var createRecordEvent = $A.get('e.force:createRecord');
                    console.log(recordTypeId);
                    console.log(returnURL);
                    console.log(entity);
                    if (createRecordEvent) {
                        createRecordEvent.setParams({
                            "entityApiName" : entity,
                            "recordTypeId" : recordTypeId,
                            "defaultFieldValues" : {                           
                                "AccountId" : objId,
                            }
                        });
                        createRecordEvent.fire();
                    }
            }
        }); 
        $A.enqueueAction(action);   
    }
})
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" extensions="Controller" lightningStylesheets="true"> 
    <apex:includeLightning />    
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />

        <div id="divId" />
            <script>
            var accId = "{!$CurrentPage.parameters.accId}";
            console.log('accId'+accId);
            $Lightning.use("c:NewOppLEXApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:OpportunityLEX",
                                           { "recordId": accId},
                                           "divId",
                                           function(cmp) {
                                               console.log('Test before URL');
                                           });
            });
            </script>
</apex:page>
```

When I run this VF Page, `e.force:createRecord` fires. However I am right now seeing a blank window as "**SetCallback**" shows after "**Test before URL**", hence createrecord event doesn't pops up(what I believe). Please let me know if I am missing something in order to call createrecord event through vf page.

Comment: What about the other console.log statements inside the IF block in the callback? Did you get correct response?

Comment: yes it did get the correct response

Answer (score 0):

It did fire; if you saw SetCallback in the console, this means the code did execute, so the event did fire. If you need the callback to execute after the event is fired, you need to make it a delayed call, which you can do with setTimeout.

```
function(cmp) {
    setTimeout( () => { console.log('Test before URL') });
});
```

However, it's not clear that this will help you solve your problem. Please read about the [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: sorry my bad, yes it did fire but after "Test before URL" , due to which createrecord event pop up doesn't show up , right now it is showing me a blank window. May be my understanding is not correct. Please help.

Comment: Seems like a limitation of using force:createRecord through VF Page as it outside of LEX/SF1 and also cannot use {!URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.New)} as it is declared to be a bug, Possible solution will be using create your own custom event handler.

Comment: I checked at my end ```createRecordEvent``` is ```undefined``` due to which it is not going further.